# How to add second project to the repository?

Tags: repository, svn

I have setup subversion 1.6.5 on Fedora.
I have decided to use a single repository for multiple projects. I have added one project, projA, to the repository. I will have more projects to add to the repository in future.

If I try to add next project with the command 
**'svn import . file:///path/to/repos'** gives
**svn: File already exists: filesystem '/usr/local/svn-repos/proj-test/db', transa
ction '1-1', path '/trunk'**.
The new projB is being added to the trunk directory of projA.

I have read the section "Adding Projects" in
**http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s04.html**
In that book, projects are added at once. But,I would like to add them one by one as new projects become ready to go. What is the proper command and/or how that can be done?

Thanks.
Banani

Comment: Sounds like you're importing your second project into the same tree as the first.  Maybe tell us the exact commands you used to import projectA, and then projectB?

Comment: command 
svn import . file:///usr/local/svn-proj/proj-test -m "import projA".
from projA directory.
And svn import . file:///usr/local/svn-proj/proj-test -m "import projA"
from projB directory

Comment: yeah, see my answer below.  You're trying to import both projects into the root of the repository.  You want to import them to their own subdirs instead.  Also: think seriously about giving each project their own repository ... I can think of very few situations where you'd want to store two projects in the same repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repository is just a tree of files.  If you wanted to have two projects in one repo (why you'd want this, I'll never understand), you would do the following:

```
$ mkdir repo
$ svnadmin create repo
$ cd /path/to/projectA
$ svn import -m "importing project A" . file:///path/to/repo/projectA/trunk
$ cd /path/to/projectB
$ svn import -m "importing project B" . file:///path/to/repo/projectB/trunk
```

go check out your project somewhere:

```
$ svn co file:///path/to/repo
```

and you should get a tree like:

```
repo/
repo/projectA
repo/projectA/trunk
repo/projectB
repo/projectB/trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

Import is only used on an initial import to the repository.

If you want multiple projects in one repository then you can make a directory with directories for each project within it.

Since you have already imported you can make and add directories to your working copy for each new project you need.

Comment: Thanks Appak. That means, if I have projA and projB to add to repository, first I will import a directory namely 'project' to the repository and then add projA(dir), projB(dir) to that working copy. Am I correct?